# Release app on mac os with privileged helper tool

Tags: macos

My app contains Privileged Helper tool and when I build locally everything is work.

But when I'm doing this:

1. create a deployment file via Product - Archive
2. Install this app
3. Open

My app can not open, moreover it closed automatically I assume 'cause I can not find an offer window where I should to enter a password for accessing permission for my tool.

But If I run my build via Xcode and trying to open releasing version everything is fine. The window is show and after entered a password my tool is located in LauchDaemons folder and so forth. That is the problem.

Maybe I missed something in the distribution phase?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the Console when you try to launch your app?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka thanks for reply. I guess I can not see them 'cause I have a production version and trying to install like ordinary user. I figured out that my problem linked with AuthorizationCreate failure and I'm wonder why on debug build everything fine but on production version we have an error.

Comment: okay, I got it. Found an error. Thanks for tip dude.